# How can I get the IDs of a Facebook user's friends?

Tags: facebook, friends, list, friend-list

How can I get the IDs (or links) of a Facebook user's friends? Any app for that? His/her friends are visible to everyone. I can get his/her friends IDs manually but it takes long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good start is : http://developers.facebook.com/

Just head for the documentation and in the API for user you will find it returns:

( http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user ) :

friends : The user's friends
(Available to everyone on Facebook)

--> An array of JSON objects containing friend id and name fields

For example see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340271